# Split Words in the comment text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a macro which will split the comment. My supervisor wants to prioritize the comments, e.g.:

Low : Comment 1

Medium : Comment 2

High: Comment 3

The output should be displayed in Excel with the following headings.
I was able to write a macro to export comments from Word to an Excel file, however I am struggling to add this code snippet to split the comment text.

```
Comment ID  |Page|  Section/Paragraph Name  |Comment Scope  |Comment text   |Priority   |Reviewer   |Comment Date|
1   |1| 1.1heading1|    example| heading|   Comment 1   |Low    |BlueDolphin    |1/1/1|
2|  2|  1.2heading  |example2   |Comment 2  |Medium|    BlueDolphin|    1/1/1|
3|  3   |1.3heading|    3example3|Comment 3 |High   |BlueDolphin    |1/1/1|
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you show the existing macro you wrote, and explain better what you mean by "split the comment text" (split each word of the comment into a different Excel cell?), we **might** be able to assist.

Comment: When a comment is added reviewers will add the comment saying 'Low : Comment 1" or "Medium :Comment 2". The macro should trim based on the delimiter ":" . The output should display in two different columns "Low" is in one column and "Comment 1"in another. Comment should display the entire sentence after the ":". I hope I have given more clarity now. I am unable to paste my entire code here.Is there anyway I can send a message to you

Comment: I'm not sure why you are unable to paste the relevant code.  (It doesn't need to be the entire code, just the bits that are relevant to taking the comment and putting it into Excel - enough that we could dump it into our own copy of Word and run it so that we can see why your code isn't doing what you want.)  Just click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47703103/edit) link and then copy/paste the code into the question.  And then, to make it look nice, highlight the code and press Ctrl-K to indent it 4 characters.

Comment: FWIW, I'm guessing it just needs one `Instr`, one `Left` and one `Mid` added to your code and it will work.

Comment: I have posted my code here as well. http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?61511-Split-Words-in-the-comment-text-VBA-Macro&p=373914#post373914

Comment: Why don't you post your code here so that we can assist you?

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty straightforward.  Just turn on the Macro Recorder, select the cells of interest, click Data > Text to Columns, and follow the prompts.  Turn off the Macro Recorder when done.  That's it.

Comment: This is for word not excel. I am trying to convert word to excel in the macro

Comment: @bluedolphin The suggestion is to do that in Excel, which will give you the code that you can then incorporate into your existing Word VBA code.  (Just as you use Excel VBA within your current Word VBA code to update values in cells, etc, you can use Excel VBA to perform "Text to Columns".)  Personally, I don't think this suggestion is the best way to do it, but it is probably the best you are going to get if you aren't willing to post your code so that we can give something tailored to your specific situation.